# How to use token authorization with axios in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, token

I have this function in react.js that should access a django rest framework using a token access:

```
 getAll(token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Token " + token
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/todos/');
```

I keep getting:

GET http://localhost:8000/api/todos/ 401 (Unauthorized)

I have tried calling the http request on [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) and everything seems fine. the successful curl request from [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) is

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos \
  --header 'Authorization: Token 9a60ef4a5fbaab1b0fa9c3e8e8a5626b757e148d' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --cookie csrftoken=MtpItNeHebjs7OaAfTTJBO3x4ezh5FfnVg1mNjOuNTy1piK9DXxSusb4oxW2qy1e
```

How would I implement this token request using axios in react.js

Comment: Can you share the successful request from insomnia as a curl?

Comment: I have added the successful curl request to the question

Comment: So in your curl you are sending a csrf token, where/how are you setting that on the axios request or axios default settings?

Comment: I added the token while authorizing the file using ```axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Token " + token```.  am I wrong setting the authorization token this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be

```
"Token " + token
```

I think the rest API is looking for a bearer token as authorization so you might want to use

```
 axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token
```

Comment: The bearer token isn't working. Though I just added the successful curl request from [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/). you can look at it in the question

Comment: Can you try logging your Axios response/error and see if the token is actually getting attached to your request if it is not I would suggest you try setting default headers a bit early like after login or when the app loads of course by seeing if the user already is logged in.

Comment: I just logged the axios error and the token was not attached to the request

Comment: Ah so you might want to attach token early on as I suggested earlier or  attach the token manually in every request by passing Authorization in  params of every API request

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Mandip Giri's answer would work.

Though for convenience sake I would suggest creating file `src/utility/axiosInstance.js` or something equivalent with contents like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://example.com',
});

export const setToken = (token) => {
  const auth = `Bearer ${token}`;
  axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = auth;
};
```

Than you import axiosInstance and setToken method into whatever component you need and use accordingly to the requirements.